# How to Configure Callbacks to Cards in Plotly Dash App

Tags: python, callback, plotly, plotly-dash, kpi

I'm working on creating a Python-based COVID19 dashboard with Plotly Dash.  I want to have some cards near the top of the page displaying population/case/death KPIs that update based on the selection of a dropdown menu.  I'm a little confused on how to configure the callback section to make the cards reactive.

Here is my code so far:

```
#Import packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

#Read in data and manipulate
who_data = pd.read_csv("https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-data.csv")
pops = pd.read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curran/0ac4077c7fc6390f5dd33bf5c06cb5ff/raw/605c54080c7a93a417a3cea93fd52e7550e76500/UN_Population_2019.csv")

pops = pops[['Country','2020']]
pops['2020'] = pops['2020']*1000

who_data.rename(columns={'New_cases': 'New Cases', 'Cumulative_cases': 'Cumulative Cases', 'New_deaths': 'New Deaths','Cumulative_deaths': 'Cumulative Deaths'}, inplace=True)

country_choices=who_data['Country'].unique()
metric_choices=who_data.columns[4:]

#Initialize graph
fig = px.line(who_data, x="Date_reported", y="New Cases")

#Define cards
card1 = dbc.Card([
    dbc.CardBody([
        html.H4("Card title", className="card-title",id="card_num1"),
        html.P("Current Population", className="card-text",id="card_text1")
    ])
],
    style={'display': 'inline-block',
           'width': '33.3%',
           'text-align': 'center',
           'color':'white',
           'background-color': 'rgba(37, 150, 190)'},
    outline=True)

card2 = dbc.Card([
    dbc.CardBody([
        html.H4("Card title", className="card-title",id="card_num2"),
        html.P("This is some card text", className="card-text",id="card_text2")
        ]
     )],
    style={'display': 'inline-block',
           'width': '33.3%',
           'text-align': 'center',
           'color':'white',
           'background-color': 'rgba(37, 150, 190)'},
    outline=True)

card3 = dbc.Card([
    dbc.CardBody([
        html.H4("Card title", className="card-title",id="card_num3"),
        html.P("This is some card text", className="card-text",id="card_text3")
        ]
     )],
    style={'display': 'inline-block',
           'width': '33.3%',
           'text-align': 'center',
           'color':'white',
           'background-color': 'rgba(37, 150, 190)'},
    outline=True)

#Define app layout
app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Tabs([
        dcc.Tab(label='Country', value='tab-1', style=tab_style, selected_style=tab_selected_style,
                children=[
            html.Div([
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='dropdown1',
                    options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in country_choices],
                    value=country_choices[0]
                )
            ],style={'width': '50%',
                     'display': 'inline-block',
                     'text-align': 'center'}
            ),
            html.Div([
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='dropdown2',
                    options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in metric_choices],
                    value=metric_choices[0]
                )],style={'width': '50%',
                          'display': 'inline-block',
                          'text-align': 'center'}
            ),
            html.Div([
                card1,
                card2,
                card3
            ]),
            html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(figure=fig, id='country_plot')
            ])
        ]),
        dcc.Tab(label='Spread', value='tab-2', style=tab_style, selected_style=tab_selected_style,
                children=[
             html.P('Some stuff will go here eventually.') 

        ])
])
])



# @app.callback(
#     Output('card_num1','children'),
#     Output('card_num2','children'),
#     Output('card_num3','children'),
#     Output('card_text1','children'),
#     Output('card_text2','children'),
#     Output('card_text3','children'),
#     Input('dropdown1','value')
# )

# def update_cards(country_select):
#     new_df = who_data[(who_data.Country==country_select)]
#     c_pop = pops[pops.Country==country_select]['2020'].unique()[0]
    
#     card1 = dbc.Card([
#         dbc.CardBody([
#             html.H4(c_pop, className="card-title",id="card_num1"),
#             html.P(f"Current Population of {country_select}", className="card-text")
#         ])
#     ],
#     style={'display': 'inline-block',
#            'width': '33.3%',
#            'text-align': 'center',
#            'background-color': 'rgba(37, 150, 190)'},
#     outline=True)




@app.callback(
    Output('country_plot','figure'),
    Input('dropdown1','value'),
    Input('dropdown2','value'))

def update_figure(country_select,metric_select):
        new_df = who_data[(who_data.Country==country_select)]
        country_df = pops[pops.Country==country_select]

        fig = px.line(new_df, x="Date_reported", y=metric_select,
                      title=f'<b>{metric_select} of COVID19 for {country_select}</b>',
                      color_discrete_sequence = ["red"],
                      labels=dict(Date_reported="Date")
                     )
        fig.update_traces(mode='markers+lines',marker=dict(color="black",size=3),line=dict(width=2))
        fig.update_layout(title={'x':0.5,
                                 'xanchor': 'center',
                                 'yanchor': 'top'})
    
        return fig

app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0',port='8050')
```

I commented out the `@app.callback` section I'm confused on.  Not sure how to proceed and haven't been able to find any examples online that do this.  Or at least any that made their code available.

Can someone help point me in the right direction?  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost got it. You need to have multiple outputs wrapped in a list, and the callback should `return` a tuple or list that is the same length as your number of outputs.

```py
@app.callback(
   [
    Output('card_num1','children'),
    Output('card_num2','children'),
    Output('card_num3','children'),
    Output('card_text1','children'),
    Output('card_text2','children'),
    Output('card_text3','children'),
   ],
    Input('dropdown1','value')
)

def update_cards(country_select):
    # perform some logic here
    return output_1, output_2, output_3, output_4, output_5, output_6  
    # these variable names can be whatever you want
```

Comment: Thank you @coralvanda!  

So, I added this:     return ([card1], [card2], [card3], [card_text1], [card_text2], [card_text3]) and am still having issues.  Not getting any warnings, so not sure what's going on.  Code seems to be ignored.

Comment: What happens if you don't wrap them all in brackets?

Comment: Still nothing.  Code seems to be ignored.

Comment: Any errors or messages from the browser console?

Comment: I tinkered with it some more and got it to work - reworked the cards a bit so they were all wrapped up in a dbc.Row and then used the row id to reference in the callback section for just 3 elements (card1, card2, card3) instead of all 6 elements!  Thank you for your help!  You helped move me in the right direction!

Comment: Could you please include a working version at the bottom of your question?